# Injecting angular directive through mapquest library. Directive not detected

Tags: angularjs, mapquest

I have a directive, `<flightpoint></flightpoint>`.

I need to add this directive to [Mapquest's map](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/poi#htmlpoi) via `map.addShape()`.

However, **angular is not aware of the new directive on the map**, therefore it doesn't process it (its blank html).

```
MQA.withModule('htmlpoi', function() {
  var poi=new MQA.HtmlPoi( {lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089} );
  poi.setHtml("<flightpoint></flightpoint>", -6, -20, 'mqa_nostyle_htmlpoi');
  var x = routeMap.addShape(poi);
});
```

---

A few things I've tried.....

**1.** $compile

```
MQA.withModule('htmlpoi', function() {
  var poi=new MQA.HtmlPoi( {lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089} );
  poi.setHtml($compile("<flightpoint></flightpoint>")($scope), -6, -20, 'mqa_nostyle_htmlpoi');
  var x = routeMap.addShape(poi);
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

**Result:** [object Object] is displayed on the map instead of my directive.

**2.** angular.bootstrap()

```
MQA.withModule('htmlpoi', function() {
  var poi=new MQA.HtmlPoi( {lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089} );
  poi.setHtml("<flightpoint></flightpoint>", -6, -20, 'mqa_nostyle_htmlpoi');
  var x = routeMap.addShape(poi);
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

**Result:** "Error: App Already Bootstrapped with this Element 'document'"

If I was able to compile it after its been added that would be okay too.

Comment: Did you remember to include the directive's javascript file in your html in script tags? I have forgotten before...

Comment: Good thought. Yes. If I put the directive inside the page it works, it only doesn't work when I inject it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little sloppy but its working for me.

I'm able to add a dummy tag and insert compiled angular into it.

```
MQA.withModule('htmlpoi', function() {
  var poi=new MQA.HtmlPoi( {lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089} );
  poi.setHtml("<span id=\"insertDirectiveHere\"></span>", -6, -20, 'mqa_nostyle_htmlpoi');
  routeMap.addShape(poi);

  // now that you've added the span we can insert compiled angular on that tag
  var domElem = document.getElementById('insertDirectiveHere');
  domElem.innerHTML = "<flightpoint></flightpoint>";
  $compile(domElem)($scope);
});
```